# MoreLikeThisQuery using SolrTemplate in Spring data

Tags: solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

My question is very simple, can a More like this query be performed using SolrTemplate in Spring data? I cannot find the class MoreLikeThisQuery like the one in Elastic Search.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no functionality **inside** Spring Data Solr, however, this is relatively easy to add such functionality by yourself.

In short terms, you need to add a Solr Server RequestHandler, that will use default `solr.MoreLikeThisHandler` and just invoke this handler from the repository.

There is a nice blog post about it [here](http://nixmash.com/post/morelikethis-queries-with-spring-data-solr), containing all needed details.